# javascript event doesn't recognize my function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have an ajax script which is used to set the user location, the form input is a

```
<select id="region" onchange="city('/ajax-city.php')" ...>
   <option>

<select ..\>
   <option...>
```

when one of the options in the first select list is changed (onchange) an ajax request is sent to the server and the response is proccessed and the second `<select>` is updated.

it's the function used to update the `<select>`

```
var city = function(page)
{
    if(xhro){ // stands for Xml Http Request Object
      var fv = document.getElementById('region').value;
      var obj = document.getElementById('city-element');
      obj.innerHTML="<span style=\"display:block; width:200px; float:right; padding:0 10px 10px 0; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:12px;\"> please wait.. </span>";
      xhro.open("POST",page);
      xhro.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhro.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xhro.readyState==4 && xhro.status==200)
        {
            obj.innerHTML = "<select name=\"city\"  onchange=\"subcity('ajax-subcity.php')\" id=\"city\" >"+xhro.responseText+"</select>";
        }
      }
      xhro.send("city=" + fv);
}
```

as you can see my function adds onchange attribute in order to send another ajax request when the `<select name="city">` onchange event is trigged, but when i click on the next option in the `<select name="city">`, in console in firebug i get this error

```
subcity is not a function
```

`subcity("ajax-subcity.php");`

and when i type the function in console firebug recognizes it, i think when an ajax request updates DOM elements the events are not handle like when the page normally loads.

but that is just a suggestion consider that the function `city()` is handled and updates `<select name="city>"` but in the next level(`subcity()`) no update happens

and creating the `<option ..>` s is done with php script.

it think the problem in not the subcity() function because it works in firebug BTW it's good to be mentioned.

```
var subcity = function(page){
alert("problem solved");
if(xhro){
    var fv = document.getElementById('city').value;
    var obj = document.getElementById('subcity-element');
    obj.innerHTML="<span style=\"display:block; width:200px; float:right; padding:0 10px 10px 0; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:12px;\"> please wait</span>";
    xhro.open("POST",page);
    xhro.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhro.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhro.readyState==4 && xhro.status==200){
            obj.innerHTML = "<select name=\"subcity\" id=\"subcity\" >"+xhro.responseText+"</select>";
        }
    }
    xhro.send("city=" + fv);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried invoking firebug just after creating your select? (like: `console.log(subcity);` after `obj.innerHTML = ...`, inside the `if`) Just to be sure `subcity` is already defined and/or has not been redefined when your program is in that particular state.

Comment: what is subcity ? where is it defined ? ect , since the problem is with that function you should show the code regarding the function that causes a issues.

Comment: @camus the problem is not the function, function works correctly when i call it in firebug console, the problem is that the Event is not handled to the function.

Comment: I dont know , i dont have the entire code to tell you why it doesnt work. want some help or not ? then show the damn code.

Comment: @camus i did. check the question :D

Comment: @Tamil yes, but after your comment i placed it before city, it didn't help. :) thanks

Comment: after selecting a city , type subcity() in the firebug console and check if subcity is still a function or not. if not , write typeof subcity to know what is subcity.

Comment: i hadn't have heard of stack trace, did a search and tried console.trace(); in console, nothig showed up. :|

Comment: I answered you , check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i quote :

```
   if(xhro.readyState==4 && xhro.status==200){
            obj.innerHTML = "<select name=\"subsity\" id=\"subcity\" >"+xhro.responseText+"</select>";
        }
```

Change the **subcity** id you use in your select ,please use **"sub-city"** instead of "subcity" or it will overwrite your subcity function !!!

**ids are used by javascript , that's why they must be unique.** , it is not just for CSS.

EDIT :

do the same for city and city function

PS : your code is a mess , seriously ! fix it.

Comment: i haven't heard such a smart answer in last 3 months (i've been asking !) ... that was great .. !! thank you very very much ...

Comment: Well, IE is the only browser where IDs magically become globals. Nice catch.